# VBA: How to copy a row and paste the row underneath using the Offset function

Tags: vba, excel

The offset function is traditionally used for cells but I would like to use it to copy and paste entire rows.  How do you use the offset function for entire rows?  Here is my code, however, it is not working.  Thank you.

```
Sub Macro()

Rows("2:2").Select
Selection.Copy
Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid Select wherever possible.

```
Sub Macro()

Dim r As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For r = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    With Cells(r, 1).EntireRow
        .Copy
        .Resize(2).Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
    Cells(r + 1, "S").Value = DateAdd("m", 1, Cells(r, "S"))
    Cells(r + 2, "S").Value = DateAdd("m", 2, Cells(r, "S"))
Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.  I need to copy and paste every row twice.  I simply added another .copy .offset to your code and it worked twice.  How might I create a loop that does this for every original row in a spreadsheet?

Comment: My pleasure. Have amended above to copy twice without having to repeat the copy line. So you have say ten rows and you want each one duplicated twice?

Comment: Yes, say you have 10 rows. I would want each one duplicated twice to have a total of 30 rows at the end.  Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Have amended above to duplicate each row from the last row with data in column A to row 1 so you may need to adjust that (in the For line)

Comment: This is awesome, you really saved me a lot of time, thank you!  If you have time to answer one more question, I'd be very grateful:  In column S I have an estimated shipping date on each row.  Do you know how I could make the first copy of a row have a date one month in advance and the second copy of the row have a date that's two months in advance?  Thanks again!

Comment: I got run time error 13, "Type Mismatch" on the line of code: Cells(r + 1, "S").Value = DateAdd("m", 1, Cells(r, "S"))

Comment: That suggests the value in S is not an actual date. What is the value?

Comment: I realized the mistake, the sheet had been adapted and their was not a proper date in S.  Now that there is only dates in column S, I'm getting a compile error on the DateAdd command

Comment: The format is Date:  3/14/2017 is the first one and it never got past that

Comment: OK, I think your best bet is to post a new question, and add the code above (and quote the full error). I've never actually used DateAdd before and it's not immediately obvious to me why it errors.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help that you have given me, I'll write a new question when the 90 minutes is up

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your other question? Of course a workaround would be to use the approach you were using there rather than DateAdd (though the latter should work).

Comment: I think it may be that S has not been defined

Comment: No, that's not the problem - `Cells` can accept a column letter as the column argument.